# Update azure service bus queue shared access policy programmatically

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I would like to change the primary and secondary keys of an access rule of a queue (service bus in our case) programmatically (We would like to regenerate the primary key once a day).
I would like to do this to an existing queue after it was already created.
I know this can be done from the Azure portal (by clicking on the "Regen prim key" and "Regen sec key" of the policy windows) but I didn't manage to do it from my .Net code.

My code looks as follow:

```
SharedAccessAuthorizationRule rule;
            if (!queueDescription.Authorization.TryGetSharedAccessAuthorizationRule(ruleName, out rule))
            {
                // error
            }

            rule.SecondaryKey = rule.PrimaryKey;
            rule.PrimaryKey = SharedAccessAuthorizationRule.GenerateRandomKey();
```

After this code, the rule is not changed.....

Is there another way to do it...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know this can be done from the Azure portal (by clicking on the "Regen prim key" and "Regen sec key" of the policy windows) but I didn't manage to do it from my .Net code.

Please try to call [UpdateQueue(QueueDescription) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_UpdateQueue_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_) to update the queue after you regenerate/reset the PrimaryKey for your authorization rule. And you could refer to the following sample code.

```
string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://fehanservicebustest.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey={accesskey}";
string queueName = "{queuename}";

var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);


QueueDescription queueDescription = namespaceManager.GetQueue(queueName);

SharedAccessAuthorizationRule rule;

queueDescription.Authorization.TryGetSharedAccessAuthorizationRule("fehanlistenpolicy", out rule);

string newkey = SharedAccessAuthorizationRule.GenerateRandomKey();
rule.PrimaryKey = newkey;

namespaceManager.UpdateQueue(queueDescription);
```