# How to regenerate Servicebus queue keys

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, .net-standard

I need to regenerate the ServiceBus primary and secondary keys on a periodic basis. I am able to do it in the .NET framework, but i need to do it in .NET Core or .NET 6 as it will be an Azure Function with a timer trigger.
I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, but I cannot find the corresponding methods that are in Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.... in order to generate the keys nor to update the rules.
Can someone please direct me to the documentation or sample code?
thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include the details about the SDK you are using to regenerate the keys. Also include the code which worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can regenerate the keys using the method `RegenerateKeysAsync` which is available in [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent/). It regenerates the keys at namespace level.

Alternatively, you can use below code to generate new key

```
string newPrimaryKey = SharedAccessAuthorizationRule.GenerateRandomKey();
rule.PrimaryKey = newPrimaryKey;
```

Here is a sample where you can find [Azure Service Bus Queues with ASP.NET Core Services](https://damienbod.com/2019/04/23/using-azure-service-bus-queues-with-asp-net-core-services/).

**REFERENCES:**

1. [azure-sdk-for-net/ScenarioTests.TopicsTests.CRUDAuthorizationRules.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/4162f6fa2445b2127468b9cfd080f01c9da88eba/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus/tests/Tests/ScenarioTests.TopicsTests.CRUDAuthorizationRules.cs)
2. [Update azure service bus queue shared access policy programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42508813/update-azure-service-bus-queue-shared-access-policy-programmatically#)

Comment: Thanks, but Fluent is not going to be supported much longer.... "This package is in low maintenance mode and being phased out". I should have also mentioned that we need to use Azure Functions..... so i don't think that ASP.NET is the answer